# How to get value out of promise .then | callback returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I use promise to handle async method `getPropoalByPeriod` but I can't get the `obj` data out of the `foo` function where `console.log(89,foo(mycallback()))` prints undefined. Please help to get data outside so that I can process them.

```
function foo(callback) {
    var MyPromises = periods.map((p) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            myFunctions.getPropoalByPeriod(p.id, localStart, function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(62, err);
                    return reject(err);
                } else
                    var obj = {
                        id: p.id,
                        name: p.name,
                        savedServices: rows[0] ? rows[0].services : '',
                    };
                resolve(obj)
            })
        })
    })
    Promise.all(MyPromises)
    .then((p) => {
        callback(p)
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(79, err));
}

function mycallback(res) {
    console.log(85, res)
    return res
}
foo(mycallback)
console.log(89, foo(mycallback()))
```

This issue is different from what is on SO. It is using map() where I couldn't figure out how to apply await compared to the straightforward example of promise or async/await.

Comment: Don't use a callback. Just return the promise. Then call it as `foo().then(mycallback)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then` accepts a function and send the result of the `Promise` to that function (the first argument of your `callback` function).

Promises are asynchronous by nature, and their output is not immediately available. That's why we use `then` method to get the result.

In your code, `mycallback` receives the result of all the Promises, and the value `res` (that is printed along with value `85`) is what you get from the promises.

Remember, that because you used `Promise.all` on an array of promises, you get an array of results from all the succeeded promises. This means that `res` is an array, not a single value.

Your code suffers from some other problems. The first call to your `foo` method is good, and correctly prints the results. Your second call however (`console.log(89,foo(mycallback()))`) is incorrect, because instead of passing a function to `foo`, you are passing the result of calling `callback()`, which is `undefined`, to the `foo` function. Remove that line, and everything should be working.

Here is the complete revised code:

```
function foo() {
  var MyPromises = periods.map((p) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      myFunctions.getPropoalByPeriod(p.id, localStart, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(62, err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          var obj = {
            id: p.id,
            name: p.name,
            savedServices: rows[0] ? rows[0].services : '',
          };
          resolve(obj);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  return Promise.all(MyPromises);
}

// Pure promises:

foo().then(r => console.log(r));

// or using async/await:

async function run() {
  console.log(await foo());
}

run();

//
```

Remember, the point of using promises is freeing you from using callbacks. So there is no need to pass a callback to `foo`.

You can use `.then` or `await` to retrieve the value of a `Promise`. You can only use `await` in an async function; so you cannot use `await` in global score, and you have to define a function, and call it. So in your case, using `.then` is easier.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. But would you help in providing a mechanism to get the data outside? at the place of `console.log(89,foo(mycallback()))` ?

Comment: That's not possible. There is absolutely *no way* to get the result of a promise *synchronously*. To make your code more readable and easier to maintain, you can use async/await feature of ES2017/TypeScript.

Comment: you said `This means that res is an array, not a single value.` , but console at least shouldn't say undefined, it will say array, right?

Comment: `but it is safer to put them in place` How is that? If you know how ASI works, there's no issue. It's not "unsafe", it's just different than your personal coding style preference.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan I tried `async/wait` and no benefit, would you mind if you apply it and update your answer? I will appreciate that and mark it as best answer if it works. thank yoou.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts There *are* situations where forgetting semicolons results in undesired behavior. This code is safe, but it is a good practice to put the semicolons after every statement. It is just safer.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan [No it's not.](https://standardjs.com/) Failing to learn the _very few, very specific_ situations where adding semicolons is actually necessary at all, is what causes "undesired behavior". It has nothing to do with "safety", and any static analysis tool / linter worth its salt can easily catch such operator errors.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts OK. It seem you're more right than me! But I am in habit of adding them because I am a C family developer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ... and I totally dislike staring some lines with a semicolon!

Comment: @MohammadDehghan sure but the point of that requirement is to discourage you from writing lines that start with a `(`, `[`, or prefixed unary operator in the first place. The only fairly common case I encounter the need is ES6-style variable swap, e.g. `;[a, b] = [b, a]`

Comment: thank you for the code, I will try it and give feedback.

Comment: thank you Mr. @MohammadDehghan, you did a great job, it worked, it is the best answer!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I explained how this post is different. Please check the post. And would you help me to make it different so to remove the duplicate in the title? maybe the title should be updated.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan may you upvote the post please?

Comment: @Diamond No. Sorry. StackOverflow doesn't work like this. Votes are earned through good posts. Your post (question) shows lack of basic knowledge about the concept you're asking about.

Comment: @Diamond I upvoted your post. But please do your homework before posting questions (study about the subject, and try to understand what's happening in the code).

Comment: thank you, I actually spent days on that, yet the answer was easy but I have not come to it! Thank you again.